# SQL concatenate columns into string and only pull address

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have 4 fields that are address fields, but the address fields can be blank and have a persons name within one of the 4 fields.  The name is usually before the start of the address.  What I need to do is remove and names and empty string and only pull the core address or column that starts with a number.

For Example:

```
Select sourceaddr1, sourceaddr2, sourceaddr3, sourceaddr4
From MyTable
```

Results:
[image]

What I need to see is the core address only in a single string
Like this..

```
10767CHILDRESSCT
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took this a little different direction.

First I concatenated the 4 sourceaddr fields together in one temp table like this.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#core') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #core

SELECT DISTINCT             
,'ADDR2'    =   REPLACE(SOURCEADDR1, ' ','')+REPLACE(SOURCEADDR2, ' ','')+REPLACE(SOURCEADDR3, ' ','')+REPLACE(SOURCEADDR4, ' ','')
into #core
  FROM table
```

Next I created another temp table and brought the concatenated field in and removed all alpha characters like this.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#coreadd') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #coreadd

 Select
, 'CoreAdd' = stuff(addr2, 1, patindex('%[0-9]%', addr2)-1, '')
into #coreadd
from #core
```

By using the `STUFF` function and the above logic I was able to get just the core address all concatenated together like this.  This logic removes any of the field that were empty strings and only looks for the first number in the string.

RESULTS:

```
10767CHILDRESSCT
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need the second filled in address field, you can use `apply` and some unpivoting logic:

```
select t.*, s.sourceaddr
from mytable t cross apply
     (select v.sourceaddr
      from (values (1, t.sourceaddr1),
                   (2, t.sourceaddr2),
                   (3, t.sourceaddr3),
                   (4, t.sourceaddr4)
           ) v(i, sourceaddr)
      where sourceaddr is not null
      order by i
      offset 1 fetch first 1 row only
     ) s;
```

EDIT:

You can also express this as:

```
select t.*, s.sourceaddr
from mytable t cross apply
     (select v.sourceaddr, row_number() over (order by i) as seqnum
      from (values (1, t.sourceaddr1),
                   (2, t.sourceaddr2),
                   (3, t.sourceaddr3),
                   (4, t.sourceaddr4)
           ) v(i, sourceaddr)
      where sourceaddr is not null
      offset 1 fetch first 1 row only
     ) s
where seqnum = 2;
```

Comment: I have sql 2014 and offset 1 fetch first 1 row only is not recognized.  Is there a different way to do this?

Comment: @BIReportGuy . . . SQL Server 2014 should recognize it . . . but it needed the `ORDER BY`.